# AngularJs Sort Table on already inserted data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, html

I've been trying to sort table data on click (ng-click if i use angularJS)
I'm getting data from database.I only need Sort functionality, if it happens through angularJs I would be very happy

Here it is what i did till now, I haven't done  much as I'm new to AngularJS

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.StudentModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Students</h2>

<div><button class="create btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create New</button></div>
<br/>
<table class="table" ng-app="StudentApp">
    <tbody ng-controller="StudentCtrl">
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th ng-click="">First Name</th>
        <th ng-click="">Last Name</th>
        <th>Profile picture</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var student in Model._StudentList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@student.StudentID</td>
            <td>@student.FirstName</td>
            <td>@student.LastName</td>
            <td>
            <a class="example-image-link" href="~/Images/@student.PhotoURL" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="@student.FirstName @student.LastName profile Picture"><img class="example-image" width="60" height="40" src="~/Images/@student.PhotoURL" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <a href="#" class="edit" data-studentid="@student.StudentID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil img-rotate" title="Edit"></span></a> 
             &nbsp;<a href="#" class="details" data-studentid="@student.StudentID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign img-rotate" title="Infomation"></span></a> 
             &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete" data-studentid="@student.StudentID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove img-rotate" title="Remove"></span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to sort firstName, LastName when they click on respective th tag

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sort table filter in AngularJS, which his name is OrderBy ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy))

Currently, you **cannot use that with your code**, because OrderBy filter only works if **AngularJS writes himself the table**.

Example :

```
<table class="friend">
<tr>
  <th>
    <a href="" ng-click="order('name')">Name</a>
    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
  </th>
  <th>
    <a href="" ng-click="order('phone')">Phone Number</a>
    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
  </th>
  <th>
    <a href="" ng-click="order('age')">Age</a>
    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
  </th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your case, the table is written in the view, and I think the only way to do it now with your code, is using a jQuery plugin.
Sadly, you loose the power of AngularJS...

**Solution :**

A solution would be to use ng-init attribute :

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=[
    {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
    {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]">

<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="x   in names">
         {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And you can use names variable in your controller, like :

```
console.log($scope.names); // Display the names
```

Comment: oh thats so sad, can i bind my MVC Model data to AngularJs
I mean like we bind JSON data
var people = [];
 eg : $scope.People = json.data

Comment: oh thats so sad, can i bind my MVC Model data to AngularJs
I mean like we bind JSON data
var app = angular.module('studentApp', []);
app.controller('StudntCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
htp.get('Student.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.People = data;
});
});
like wise can i bind MVC model data to $scope.People ???

Comment: Yes, you can set variables in your view by using ng-init : [example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp).
Then, you can use it usually in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

oh thats so sad, can i bind my MVC Model data to AngularJs
I mean like we bind JSON data

```
var app = angular.module('studentApp', []);
app.controller('StudntCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    htp.get('Student.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.People = data;
    });
});
```

like wise can i bind MVC model data to $scope.People ???